# Why is causal AR1 + drift + trend weakly stationary

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, trend

I'm a bit confused about the definition of weakly stationarity

from looking at the definition of weakly stationarity, it requires:
E(xt) = E(xt−j ) = µ ∀ j
var(xt) = var(xt−j ) = σ^2 ∀ j
cov(xt, xt−j ) = γj ∀ t

But from looking at the graph of causal AR(1) + drift + trend,
I don't think the E(xt) is constant (mean is increasing as t increases),
also the variance is not constant from the graph,
so why is causal AR(1) + drift + trend weakly stationary?
[image]

Comment: Hi: if you add a trend to a  weakly stationary series ( in other words, a $b \times t $ term ), then the process could be termed trend stationary which means that, if you de-trended, you'd get a weakly stationary process. But,  I don't see how you can tell that the variance is not constant ? Also, it would be better if you wrote out the whole equation so that it was clear what you meant by drift ? Are you just adding a constant to the process ?